# How does Dependency Inversion solve switch cases?

Tags: java, coding-style, clean-architecture

I want to understand how Dependency Inversion gets rid of switch cases.

Consider a service that needs to communicate with several databases.

```java
class StockUpdater {
  private final DataStore datastore;
  public StockUpdater(DataStore datastore) {
    this.datastore = datastore;
  }
  public void update(StockItem item, int quantity){
    datastore.update(item, quantity);
  }
}

public interface DataStore {
  update(StockItem item, int quanity)
}

public class PostgresAdapter implements DataStore {
...
  public void update(StockItem item, int quantity) {
    // Add item to database
  }
}

public class MariaDBAdapter implements DataStore {
...
  public void update(StockItem item, int quantity) {
    // Add item to database
  }
}
```

We remembered our friend abstraction and used `interface`. Whereas in the past, we might have used hideous `if/else` or `switch`  statements instantiating for instances `new MariaDBAdapter`.
Now I understand that we solved this issue by using an interface and taking the logic (`if/else` conditions ) out of the class `stockUpdater` and the `update()` method; however, I thought we shift the problem. Since we need to provide a `Datastore` when we create a `StockUpdater`. And this needs an again a condition when to create a `PostgresAdapter` or a `MariaDBAdapter`.

it would just be

```java
DataStore myDatastore = null 

if (...){
  myDatastore  = new PostgresAdapter()
}
else {
  myDatastore  = new MariaDBAdapter()
}
StockUpdater myUpdater = new StockUpdater(myDatastore)

...
```

If my goal is to get rid of tedious `if/else` conditions, this looks quite the same. If I wanted to take the logic out of  `StockUpdater`, then sure, this is great.

I hope I made myself clear. I might have a thinking blockage. My question how did  Dependency Inversion gets rid of switch cases? Or what I am missing in my reasoning.

Comment: Dependency injection means the name of the actual updater class comes from a config file and is constructed using reflection - not using a if/else.  Using something like `Class c = Class.forName(className); Object o = c.newInstance();`  That way the config file determines which one is created.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah That's autowring - often used with dependency injection, but not an essential feature of it. You can have DI without autowring. DI really just means passing dependencies to services as arguments.

Comment: It's not the switch statement itself that's the problem, it's that you tend to switch on the same or on a closely related constant in other places in the codebase; the form of the switch sometimes being similar, sometimes looking different, until you look at it in a particular way. Once you find that "particular way" of looking at the problem (once you find the right abstraction, or a set of abstractions), polymorphism (not dependency injection specifically) allows you to deal with this proliferation by confining the switch in a single place.

Comment: Here is an  example of how to use reflection to remove the if/else completely: https://onlinegdb.com/08r406JatR

Comment: @bdsl: Not to one-up, but DI tends to refer to _automated_ injection. There's a scale here: (1) **IoC** refers to injecting dependencies, be it manually or not (2) **DI** refers to a dependency factory (i.e. automated chained dependency instantiation) (3) **Autowiring** refers to hardcoding the settings of the DI container. (Disclaimer: I'm sure that there's someone out there who has different definitions, but these are the ones that fit most with all conversations I have about development)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Dependency Inversion does not remove the need for if-else or switch statements. If these statements get removed, it is a *side effect* of using dependency inversion, not the goal. There are two main benefits of DI. First, a class does not need to know how to initialize its own dependencies. This prevents a class from also needing to know the dependencies of the classes it depends on. This leads to the second benefit, which is loose coupling. Loose coupling makes it easier to test classes and change implementations without mass code changes. For instance, switching from a relational database to a document database like MariaDB.

None of this mentions `if` or `switch` statements. The reality is that something *somewhere* must make the decision. By utilizing DI and polymorphism you only make the decision once. That is why people say dependency inversion "solves switch cases" because you do not need to make the decision to use MariaDB every place that needs to perform data access.

Typically a factory object, dependency injection container, or custom written code in the Composition Root of the application makes the decision so the rest of the code remains ignorant, and instead relies on the abstractions provided by dependency inversion.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I think bringing  
>  class does not need to know how to initialize its own dependencies
to the foreground <put it into perspective. I got tangled up in the implication (getting rid of conditions) of Dependency Inversion and mistakenly taken it as presumption. Just as clarification is this kind of question in the scope of this substack? thanks again/

Comment: @A.Dumas: Yes, this question is perfectly on-topic for this site. Ignore the down-voters.